# How can I determine which SQL db my Access app is pointing to?

Tags: connection, microsoft-access, sql-server, microsoft-access-2010

There is no ini file containing any kind of connection string so it must be embedded somewhere, but where can I find this?

The linked table manager appears to point to something but doesn't give details of any underlying db as such

Anywhere else I should check?

EDIT: Not quite sure why this has been flagged for closure due to not enough information.
The Microsoft Access 2010 is consuming a SQL Server database. It is not immediately apparent which database it is in fact consuming, ergo, how can I find this out

Comment: What are you talking about, dude? What do you try to do, what language, why do you ask here and not at SO?

Comment: Because it's not programming. How is determining which db I am pointing at programming? What do you mean "what language". English, do you speak it?

Comment: I mean programming language, what else?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. I just need to know where I can find which database it is pointing to.

Comment: Give us please a fair chance to help you, adolf, and provide finally more infos!

Comment: Not sure what extra information I can give? It's a Microsoft Access 2010 application that does not use access as the database but instead (as is entirely possible) uses SQL Server as its datasource. There does not appear to be a locally held ini file that contains any information about any SQL Server databases nor are there any DSNs on the machine yet still it works fine. So, it is connecting to *a* SQL Server, but to which one of say 'prod', 'dev' etc?

Comment: Told you it wasn't programming related :D

Answer (score 1):

Open Access

Hit F11 to show the side bar
expand tables, go to any linked table
hover over the table and it will show the connection string value in the tooltip

OR

right click on the sidebar and under "navigation options" select "show hidden objects"
then under 'tables' go to MSysObjects and take a look at the values held in the 'connect' column